# Email message says content is None, any idea why?

Tags: python

I made a little php mail() routine. It sends emails to me, homework. I can see the content in the mail, looks like this:

```
Studentnr = 1725010130
Q1 = B
Q2 = B
Q3 = F
Q4 = E
Q5 = T
Q6 = T
Q7 = T
Q8 = T
Q9 = B
Q10 = F
Q11 = F
Q12 = C
Q13 = F
Q14 = F
Q15 = C
Q16 = D
```

I run a python script to download the answers. Looks like this:

```
for uid, message_data in server.fetch(unseenMessages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
        print('UID is ' + str(uid))
        print(email_message.get('Subject'))
        messageSubject = str(email_message.get('Subject'))
        print('Message subject is ' + messageSubject)
        if not len(messageSubject) == 15:
            continue
        file = messageSubject + '.txt'
        theFile = open(path + file, 'w')
        rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
        try:
            message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[uid][b'BODY[]'])
            text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
            saveText = text.rstrip()
            theFile.write(saveText)
            theFile.close()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Previously, I got the students to write the emails themselves. Worked OK.

Now I am trying textboxes and radio buttons and php to send me the mail.

Now I get this error:

```
Number of unseen messages is 46
UID is 236
1725010132Week9
Message subject is 1725010132Week9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getAnswersFromEmail17BEv3.py", line 64, in <module>
    text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

The body of the email is not empty, I can see it. Any idea why I am getting this error?

I tried

```
except TypeError
```

and now I have a folder full of empty text files!!

EDIT: fixed. I fixed the empty files quite simply, I put a header in the mail() function:

> mail($to1, $subject, $body, $headers);

The header is:

> $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

In the download routine, I have so far only got pyzmail to work for me. The line that caused my problem was:

> text =
>   message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)

Must have had the wrong charset.

I still get

> Message body is None

and I have no idea why, but the routine now successfully downloads the data I need.

Comment: Looks like all python to me. Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Coz the email comes from php mail() functions. Before, I got the students to write the mail, I did not have this problem.

Comment: can you check php `error_log`? from the terminal, `php -i | grep error_log` will tell you where it is

Comment: @delboy1978uk I don't have php installed on this laptop. I thought it only worked on servers. I have copied the text which server.fetch(unseenMessages, 'RFC822').items() displays in my idle3 python shell. All my data are in there, I can see them. As a work around, I'll write a little routine to grab it from text. It always starts 'studentnr = '

Answer (score 1):

Can you type `type(message.text_part.charset)` into your shell? Does it say `string`?
If not you can try:
`text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(string(message.text_part.charset))`, but I have no idea if .decode refers to the codecs library or not.

Comment: unseenMessages is very long. Do you know the code to just get 1 message by uid? Something like server.fetch('6', 'RFC822').items() except that doesn't do it. I'm in China, expressvpn is losing the battle with the Chinese govt. Often I can't even get here!

Comment: It would be easier if I could examine just 1 message, try and find the problem and or a solution.